# radius and center of curvature of parametric curve

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces

> Find radius of curvature and center of curvature of curve whose parametric coordinates are $x=t,y=t^2,z=4t^3$ at $t=1$

My try

Given $r(t)=ti+t^2j+4t^3j$

First we calculate $T$ from velocity vector

$v=i+2tj+12t^2k\Longrightarrow |v|=\sqrt{1+4t^2+144t^4}$

So $$T=\frac{v}{|v|}=\frac{i+2tj+12t^2k}{\sqrt{1+4t^2+144t^4}}$$

$$\kappa=\frac{1}{|v|}\bigg|\frac{dT}{dt}\bigg|$$

$$\kappa=\frac{1}{(1+4t^2+144t^4)}|2j+24tk|$$ at $t=1$

We have $\displaystyle \kappa= \frac{\sqrt{580}}{149}$

So radius of curvature is $\displaystyle \frac{149}{\sqrt{580}}$
How do i find centerof curvature Help me

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how to find the unit normal vector $\mathbf{N}$? Since the unit normal vector always looks inward in the direction orthogonal to the tangent vector, it's precisely the unit vector giving us the direction of the radius of the [osculating circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_circle). So for a point $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}(t)$ on a curve, the corresponding center of curvature is $\mathbf{x}+\rho\mathbf{N}$, where $\rho=1/\kappa$ is the radius of curvature (that you've already found).